# very new R user - northing and easting issue for window

Tags: r

I want to draw a polygonal map in R (R3.0.2) and am getting nowhere. my polygon data is:

```
1768233.661.5912880.909
1767890.645,5912896.291
1767796.816,5913007.04
1767764.514,5913082.411
1767813.736,5913165.474
1767964.478,5913137.786
1768067.537,5913062.415
1768112.144,5913080.873
1768149.061,5913113.175
1768185.163,5913095.389
1768234.212,5913088.382
1768197.425,5913007.801
1768435.163,5912936.284
1768435.163,5912903.982
1768358.254,5912873.218
```

and I'm Ok getting it into R, but then I need to enter northing, easting for the window which is not working - when I input:

```
mydata <- read.table("treePolygon.csv", header = TRUE)
attach(mydata)
X <- ppp(Easting, Northing, c(1767750.7261, 1768447.9275), c(5912848.3905, 5913186.4806))
```

I get:

```
The following object is masked from mydata (position 3):

    X1768233.661.5912880.909
The following object is masked from mydata (position 4):

    X1768233.661.5912880.909
The following object is masked from mydata (position 5):

    X1768233.661.5912880.909
```

I'm really new at this and quite lost.

Answer (score 5):

If you've copied it exactly, the problem might be that your first data pair is separated by a period instead of a comma.

Comment: Thanks, no, that period somehow got in when copying to here

Answer (score 3):

So first of all fix the comma. Second, your data has to actually have a header. This works:

```
library(spatstat)
mydata <- read.csv(header=T,text="Easting,Northing
1768233.661,5912880.909
1767890.645,5912896.291
1767796.816,5913007.04
1767764.514,5913082.411
1767813.736,5913165.474
1767964.478,5913137.786
1768067.537,5913062.415
1768112.144,5913080.873
1768149.061,5913113.175
1768185.163,5913095.389
1768234.212,5913088.382
1768197.425,5913007.801
1768435.163,5912936.284
1768435.163,5912903.982
1768358.254,5912873.218")
X <- with(mydata,ppp(Easting, 
                     Northing, 
                     c(1767750.7261, 1768447.9275), c(5912848.3905, 5913186.4806)))
X
#  planar point pattern: 15 points 
# window: rectangle = [1767750.7, 1768447.9] x [5912848, 5913186] units  
plot(X)
```

Using `attach(...)` is generally not recommended - at causes all kinds of problems unless you remember to `detach(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for putting me on the right track!

I finally drew a polygonal window using the example on p40 of Intro. to spatstat, Baddeley & Turner, for spatstat 1.8-6:

tab <- read.table(file="C:/N/0Random/0 TestData/fieldtrees.tab")
bdry <- scan("C:/N/0Random/0 TestData/field.tab", what=list(x=0,y=0))
plot(owin(poly=bdry))

[image: Polygon window - hooray]

I did have to swap the order of the points as R couldn't use them to write the polygon.

I'm now going to carry on with p40 of Intro. to spatstat, and ultimately hope to use Michael Bedward's [Circle Packing with R](http://lastresortsoftware.blogspot.co.nz/2010/07/circle-packing-with-r.html) to fill my space with different diameter circles.